# Is my EPSON projector fixable?

Tags: hardware-failure, projector

I have an EPSON EH-TW5100 projector.

Recently a green area appears and stays there. I'm not sure what the issue is or if I can fix it at home.

[image]

Comment: The question is, whether or not this can be fixed. I don't think this is fixable within the price that is cheaper than just replacing the beamer

Comment: The only *self-repair* check I could think of is to verify & exchange the HDMI cable. Using Low quality cables and not properly seated connectors can result in similar problems. But as here are some  cross-mark structures visible, I hardly give this try a chance for success. — Did you ever check, whether it's the beamer or the computer? Test by connecting a differnet computer ...

Comment: Quick fact about the projector: It uses Epson’s 3LCD technology to create the image. As the name suggests, it uses three LCDs for three light colors—probably red, green, blue. A subset of the LCDs may be to blame for this effect.

Answer (score 0):

There is a free utility that can be used to "exercise" or  "flip" pixels in a display, whether LCD or reflective, [IsMyLcdOK](https://www.softwareok.com/?seite=Microsoft/IsMyLcdOK). Though, frankly, it's a "long shot" whether it would fix the issue, it's worth trying. Use <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>F3</kbd>, <kbd>F4</kbd>, or <kbd>F6</kbd> to try freeing stuck pixels.

It's unlikely to do harm though -- and you could shut the projector lamp while this runs, if the actual display element still cycles through the colors.

Please add a comment if it helps.

<sub>*Caveat: this is not a site for software recommendations, but I could not find an alternative to this utility.*</sub>